# Jetpack Compose BottomNavigation keep item selected when navigating in

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I just started using Jetpack Compose and wanted to try out the BottomNavigation. A basic implementation with three items was no problem. Now, one of the three screens should navigate to a detail screen when clicking on a list item. The problem that occurs, is that on the detail screen the bottom navigation item is not selected anymore.

Here's my implementation:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WhoHasItTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomNavigationBar(
                            items = listOf(
                                BottomNavItem(
                                    name = "Home",
                                    route = Screen.Home.route,
                                    icon = Icons.Default.Home
                                ),
                                BottomNavItem(
                                    name = "Search",
                                    route = Screen.GameListScreen.route,
                                    icon = Icons.Default.Search
                                ),
                                BottomNavItem(
                                    name = "Profile",
                                    route = Screen.Profile.route,
                                    icon = Icons.Default.Person
                                )
                            ),
                            navController = navController,
                            onItemClick = {
                                navController.navigate(it.route) {
                                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                        saveState = true
                                    }
                                    launchSingleTop = true
                                    restoreState = true
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                        Navigation(navController = navController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(Screen.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(Screen.GameListScreen.route) {
            GameListScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(
            route = "${Screen.GameDetailScreen.route}/{gameId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("gameId") { type = NavType.IntType })
        ) {
            GameDetailScreen()
        }
        composable(Screen.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(
    items: List<BottomNavItem>,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (BottomNavItem) -> Unit
) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    BottomNavigation(
        modifier
    ) {
        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == item.route } == true,
                onClick = { onItemClick(item) },
                selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                label = { Text(item.name) },
                alwaysShowLabel = false,
                icon = {
                    Column(horizontalAlignment = CenterHorizontally) {
                        if (item.badgeCount > 0) {
                            BadgeBox(
                                badgeContent = {
                                    Text(item.badgeCount.toString())
                                }
                            ) {
                                Icon(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.name)
                            }
                        } else {
                            Icon(imageVector = item.icon, contentDescription = item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In my understanding `currentDestination?.hierarchy` should also include the root screen (GameListScreen). What am I understanding wrong here and how can I make it so screens below the root screen of each bottom navigation item still have their tab item as 'selected'?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `currentDestination?.hierarchy` is not working as expected so I suggest this work around

Add this file TapSelection.kt with selectedTapMap as the source of our selection, Add to it your main taps, I have three main taps in this example

Also we have two methods to update the map and get the selected tap

```
val selectedTapMap = hashMapOf<String, String>().apply {
    this[Screen.RidesScreen.route] = Screen.RidesScreen.route

    this[Screen.InboxScreen.route] = Screen.InboxScreen.route

    this[Screen.ProfileScreen.route] = Screen.ProfileScreen.route
}

fun updateSelectedTapMap(currentScreen: String?, newScreen: String) {
    currentScreen?.let {
        selectedTapMap[newScreen] = selectedTapMap.getOrDefault(currentScreen.firstSlot(), "")
    }
}

fun getSelectedTapOrNull(currentRout: String?) = selectedTapMap.getOrDefault(
    currentRout?.firstSlot(),
    null
)
```

After that whenever you are navigating call the update fun

```
updateSelectedTapMap(this.currentDestination?.route, Screen.NewSubScreen.route)
```

Replace selected val line with this line

```
val selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
        getSelectedTapOrNull(it.route) == screen.route
    } == true
```

Add this method, It is a string extention

```
fun String.firstSlot() = this.split("/").firstOrNull()
```

This way when you navigate to a new screen it will take the selected tap from the current one, We have one source of truth in TapSelection file, All you need to add when adding new screen is calling the update function.

That's it, Hope this will help